# Graphql fetching one object from array

Tags: graphql

In GraphQL, is it possible to fetch data with a 'filtered' array (e.g. only with a single object) instead of an array with all the (multiple) objects? For instance, by providing the 'id' property for the selected object you want to get in the query.

If yes, what needs to be changed in the below query? Just wondering if this filtering can already be done server side.

```
const selectedId = 'n32j23h'

const query = gql`
  query getData {
    dataObj {
      bigArray {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a new query in your *typeDefs*:

```
query getDataById(id: ID!): returnObjectType
```

2. Implement a resolver for that query that uses the `id` parameter to filter your `bigArray`